# How to combine pagination with getting next / previous element of a REST collection

Tags: rest, pagination

I am trying to design a REST API in which there is a paginated collection. In my current design I use a page based approach:

```
GET /entities?page=2&pageSize=25
```

Retrieving a single entity is trivial:

```
GET /entities/4
```

A user story related to this API requires that when viewing a single entity in a screen, two buttons "Previous" and "Next" enable switching to said entities. An example:

```
GET /entities?page=2&pageSize=25

  returns:

[{id: 2}, {id: 4}, {id: 17}]
```

Now, when viewing entity with id 4, the named buttons would navigate to the entities with id 2 or id 17.

My assumption is, that a client (web frontend in my case) could be able to "remember" the pagination information and use that when fetching the previous or next entity. This could be applied to eventual filters which I might add to the endpoint.

A basic idea of how to implement this would be to get the current page and for edge cases the previous and the next page (required if currently viewing the first / last resource of the collection). But that seems like an inefficient solution.

So my question is: Is my chosen pagination method even compatible with what I try to archive? If it is, how would clients use the API to archive the next/previous feature?

Comment: did u find a solution for this question?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I ended up with a frontend based solution.

Given that my constraint was that I could not change the type of pagination used, this is a crude solution:

- Frontend makes initial GET request on the paginated data. This request may not only contain pagination parameters (page + size) but also filters (color = red). This is the search context.
- The user accesses one of the items and some other view is displayed. **Important**: The search context is kept in local storage or similar.
- If the user wants to browse to the next / previous item, the search is executed again with the same search context.
- In the search result, search for the ID of the currently displayed item

  - If the currently displayed item is found, show the next / previous item
  - If it is not found, do some fallback. (In my case I chose to simply display the initial search UI)

I am not happy with this implementation as it has some major drawbacks IMO:

- Not efficient: For every browsing click, a search request is made. When not using an efficient search database like Elasticsearch this will probably cause a lot of stress on the db.
- Not perfect: If the currently displayed item is not in the search result, there is no sensible way to get the next / previous item
- If the currently displayed item is the first / last item in the search result and you want to browse back / forward, the search would have to be executed twice, once on the current page, once on the previous / next.

---

As stated, I think this is not a good solution, I am still looking for a clever, efficient way to do this.